# Using variables inside mySQL prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Is it possible to use PHP variables inside a prepared mySQL query, such as:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET $variable_field = ? WHERE field = ?");
```

It's being used within an ordering system - such that I have a session that stores the carts contents.  I won't know the total number of items ordered until the end.  So say a customer orders 10 items - I need to insert those values into item_1, item_2, item_3, etc.

What I would like to achieve:

```
<<connect to DB>>
$x = 0;
while($x < count($order_contents)) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET item_$x = ? WHERE field = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $order_contents[$x], $order_number);
    $stmt->execute();
    $x++;
}
<<close DB connection>>
```

Pretty much something along those lines.  Problem is, I can't see that it's allowing me to specify PHP variables directly within the query.  Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried it? Are you getting any errors? btw if you start having columns like item_1, item_2 in any tables then you probably need to rethink your schema.

Comment: It does appear to be working...if item_1, item_2, etc. are wrong - what might you suggest?

Comment: One table for the order details (order id, date, customer number etc) and one table for the line items (item id, order id, item details etc). Order.order_Id would be the primary key and items.order_id would reference that. This way each order can have 1..n line items and you don't need to define a new column for each line item. You should read up on database design and normalisation.

Comment: Thanks - I actually took your advise and have three separate tables - products, orders, and order details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x = 0;
while($x < count($order_contents)) {
    $x++;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE table SET item_'.$x.' = ? WHERE field = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $order_contents[$x], $order_number);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I also moved the `$x++` to the start of the loop since you want to start with `item_1`.